# Python 3.x code keeps looping endlessly, how do I fix this?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a small piece of code that chooses a number between 1 and 100, then asks the user to guess. It should give the user feedback on whether it was too low or too high and give them another guess. If they guess it correctly, it should tell them how many guesses it took.

This is my code so far -

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1, 100)

user_guesses = 0
print(random_number)  # this is for testing purposes

user_choice = int(input("Guess a random number between 1 and 100"))

while user_choice >= 1 <= 100:

    if user_choice == random_number:  # if the user inputs a number greater than 100 it will display an error message
        print("You chose wisely!")
        break

    elif user_choice != random_number:
        print("You chose poorly! Try again!")

    elif user_choice < 1:
        print("Too low! Please choose a number between 1 and 100")

    elif user_choice > 100:
        print ("Too high! Please choose a number between 1 and 100")
        user_guesses =+ 1

print("It took you", user_guesses, "attempts to guess the number. Not bad!")
```

Every time I enter a number it just throws it into a loop saying "You choose wisely!" again and again etc. Any tips would be appreciated thanks

Comment: `user_choice >= 1 <= 100` isn't doing what you want. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/

Comment: The code doesn't match the description. After the program prints `"You chose wisely!"` it will break the loop. There is no "again and again". BTW, please think about the following: in which part of the while loop can the user enter a new guess so that `user_choice` changes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that you create input before while loop.

You should make it in that way:

```
user_choice = 0

while user_choice >= 1 and user_choice <= 100:

    user_choice = int(input("Guess a random number between 1 and 100"))
    [...]
```

In this way you declare new number into guessing after the loop.
Also in the last elif statement you have

```
user_guesses =+ 1
```

what should be swapped to:

```
user_guesses += 1
```

And in my opinion it shouldn't be only when user_choice is greather than random_number but in every try if user miss a number.

Comment: `user_choice >= 1 & user_choice <= 10` should be `user_choice >= 1 and user_choice <= 100`. `&` is a bitwise operator.

Comment: `&` is binary operator. For boolean operations you should use `and`. A shorter way to write that would be `while 1 <= user_choice <= 100:`.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues with your code as it's now fixed.

First of all, let us see the working code that I modified:

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(1, 100)

user_guesses = 0
print(random_number)  # this is for testing purposes

while True:

    user_choice = int(input("Guess a random number between 1 and 100"))
    if user_choice == random_number:
        print("You chose wisely!")
        break

    elif user_choice < 1:
        print("Too low! Please choose a number between 1 and 100")

    elif user_choice > 100:  # if the user inputs a number greater than 100 it will display an error message
        print("Too high! Please choose a number between 1 and 100")
    user_guesses += 1
    print(f'guess number {user_guesses}')

print("It took you", user_guesses, "attempts to guess the number. Not bad!")
```

Now let me explain what I did:

1. I changed `while` loop to `while True` because you're setting `if` within the `while` loop.
2. I moved `user_choice` variable inside the`while` loop to get input from user multiple times.
3. I moved `elif user_choice != random_number` part to the end of `if` block, but why do you really added this part and why do you need it? I think you can remove it as it has no effect in your code in fact.
4. The `comment` you have in front of `if` statement is in fact related to `elif user_choice > 100` block, so I moved it there.
5. I de-indented `user_guesses` because it should not be part of `if...else` block, but it should be inside of `while` loop so that it increments at each iteration.
6. I added `print(f'guess number {user_guesses}')` for testing purposes to see the attempt number.

Comment: Fixing every single problem **and** explaining it. Well done.